# Unable to refresh the Access Token-Blackberry

Tags: blackberry

I am getting error as while launching my sampe code as  "facebook.FacebookException: Unable to refresh the Access Token".What does that mean?

Code that i used is

```
String NEXT_URL = "http://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html";
    String APPLICATION_ID = "140793189321103";
    String[] PERMISSIONS = Facebook.Permissions.USER_DATA_PERMISSIONS;
    ApplicationSettings as = new ApplicationSettings(NEXT_URL, APPLICATION_ID, PERMISSIONS);
    Facebook fb = Facebook.getInstance(as);

   try{
       if(fb!=null)
           try {
               User user = fb.getCurrentUser();
               System.out.println("UserClass"+user.getFirstName());
           } catch (FacebookException e) {
               System.out.println("FaceBookException"+e);
               e.printStackTrace();
           }
           else{

               System.out.println("FaceBook not connected");

           }

   }catch(Exception e){}
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block


}
```

I am getting access token as null,how can i get the particular user account initially?

Regards
Rakesh Shankar.

Comment: its a blackberry browserField bug and i dont known any cure/fix.(Except OS update) We develop facebook app and works perfectly our test devices. But our customers send tons of complaints for login issue. :( [BrowserField BUG][1]


  [1]: http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Facebook-SDK/td-p/514601/page/2

Comment: Hi,I want to know is this problem on all of 5.0 os devices ,or some  bundle of 5.0 OS.Can you ellaborate on this.i tested on 8520 device,nothing happened,

Comment: @AshrafBashir: No it is not solved yet

Answer (score 2):

instead of using User `user = fb.getCurrentUser();`
try this `user = fb.getUser("me");`

and also set all needed permission before instantiating Facebook class object

using ApplicationPermissionManager
ApplicationPermission classes